# Xamarin forms consuming API sometimes returns an incomplete JSON

Tags: c#, xamarin.forms

sometimes this code

`string stringContent = await responseMessage.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();`

would return a complete json (with "}" as the last character)

`{"enrollment-collections": ...
","assortion":null}]}`

and sometimes it would return an incomplete json (with no "}" as the last character)

`{"enrollment-collections": ...
","assortion":null}]`

It just happens randomly, sometimes it's complete sometimes it's incomplete.

**I HAVE TRIED USING POSTMAN AND POSTMAN ALWAYS GETS A COMPLETE JSON RESPONSE**

Comment: Really wish someone would help :( i don't know if it's the laravel API that's causing the problem since postman seems to not have any trouble getting a complete response.

Comment: Did you check to see if it was a server-side problem ?

Comment: @LeoZhu-MSFT yes i already did. my current fix is just to manually add that missing "}" to get serialized. Postman thou, always gets that complete response.